# monitoring the main app in c

Tags: c, multithreading, process, kernel

i have done my program mainApp that owns main() method and main() creates 5 threads, threads do some operations.. so on.

now im just wondering if my program crashes. So im gonna monitor my mainApp whether it is working or stopped. if stopped Im gonna restart/reboot the whole system.

mainApp and monitoring program have to run at the same time and monitor prog should check mainApp's status.

any suggestions pls.

PS: im om linux kernel 2.6.29.

Comment: Why would you possibly want to reboot the entire system if your app stops? O.o

Comment: cuz no way to restore it.. i guess...

Comment: I usually dodge ths issue by designing and, even more important, testing, my apps so that they do not crash.  Every night, (unless I have broken the app on that day with ongoing development), an app goes on load-test until the next morning.  If it breaks, it gets fixed .  I know that conditions on a customer site are different and so can show up more bugs, but I've never found any sort of need to go to extremes like monitoring/restarting - it's an admission of design/development/testing deficiency.  Apart from that, the monitor/restart code is more code, which means more bugs, more testing..

Comment: I think it is a little extreme to describe monitoring and restarting as going to extremes. A deployed system should always have been be well designed and tested. However, I have no problem admitting that the product may not be perfect. A monitor and restart system allows for a more graceful way to deal with unforeseen circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want a general purpose monitor, your program can monitor itself.

When the program first starts, the program itself is the monitor. Since the program is just starting, there is no "mainApp" running, so it forks itself off. The child process assumes the role of the "mainApp". The monitor now waits for the child process to die. When the child process dies, it checks the status, and ff a restart is decided, then it forks again.

```
int main () {
    /*...startup...*/
    int status;
    bool restart = true;
    while (restart) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
        case -1: /* handle error */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0: exit(mainApp());
        default: break;
        }
        pid_t child = wait(&status);
        assert(child == pid);
        restart = check_status(status);
    }
    /*...cleanup...*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so, there is no side effects if mainApp program monitors itself, right?

Comment: @fake: Should be fine, if `mainApp` is the part of the code that is launching the threads. If you have a lot of static variables, the monitor program will take up more memory than it actually. But, it's not an issue if you have swap, as the unused pages will get paged out.

Comment: actually thx for helping me out @user :) by the way how to write the check_status() function? in C i guess there is no such function

Comment: @fake: Sorry, I didn't see your comment question. `check_status` was a pseudo-code function I put in that you needed to implement to decide if the status value returned from `wait` meant that you needed to restart or not. I can't decide that part of the program for you. Regards