# C++ Linux Service - How to use init.d + auto restart?

Tags: c++, linux

I've created a linux c++ service (It's basically an app, but it handles requests over TCP/IP quite frequently).

I was wondering if there is any easy way to have it "auto restart" if something goes wrong (like it crashes) or if the server restarts?

I wasn't sure how or even if I should set it up as a service or set up an rc.d script, I'm not 100% familiar w/how to do this on linux (my server is running ubuntu if it matters).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

~ Josh

Answer (score 4):

In my product, I've created watchdog process which forks and exec service process in separate process, and waits for its termination. If, for some reason, process terminates, watchdog process will create another thread and it will start process again.

As noted in comments, you should check why it is crashed. For start, you could read program exit value.

Here is simple program to get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    create_process();
    return 0;
}

void create_process()
{
    int exit_code;
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
        exec("./your_service");
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&exit_code);
        if(WIFEXITED(exit_code))
        {
            /* Program terminated with exit */
            /* If you want, you could decode exit code here using
               WEXITSTATUS and you can start program again.
            */
            return;
        }
        else
`       {
                /* Program didn't terminated with exit, restart */
            create_process();
        }

    }
}
```

In order to start service on system startup, simply edit the `/etc/rc.local` script and append command for running your watchdog process.

Comment: a *thread* doesn't sound right.. it could corrupt the memory the watchdog thread and prevent restart..

Comment: Yes, you're right - it never come to my mind (it was very simple service). Should it use `system()` then?

Comment: You should also get some diagnostics why it has crashed. And also leave (say 3) seconds before restarting. You can get into the problem that the program tries to restart, crashs, restart - and you as a developer cannot get back into control as the hard disk is peaking, along with cpu etc.

Comment: @Burgos, no, you don't want `system()` either, just `fork` and `exec`. Not threads or `system()` needed.

Comment: @Nemanja Boric, I tested your answer and it does not behave correctly after the exec. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Frank thank you for your comment! Can you explain more in which way it doesn't behave correctly? Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, exec call will replace image of the watchdog process with your application, so after that point it's all up to monitored application, watchdog forked process no longer contains its code.

Comment: Also, few years fast forward since the answer, I would recommend using upstart's respawn stanza or systemd's alternative instead of custom solutions.

Comment: @Nemanja Boric, Your solution works sporadically. In between recursive  create_process() it fails. My exec statement is:                char* argv[5];
argv[0] = new char[64];
strcpy(argv[0],"SmartCamXi_Client_Server.exe");
argv[1] = NULL;                                                                                     execv("/home/venkat/DevelopmentX64/SmartCamXi_Hybrid_Linux/Debug/SmartCamXi_Client_Server.exe", argv);                                                                                                         Please  advise how to make it work continuously or as a daemon.

Comment: @Nemanja Boric, I am beginning to understand the elegance of your solution. This C# code obviates the need for recursive child processes in Ubuntu Linux 15.10 . Please let me know your comments.                  private void MainLoop (ServiceBase [] services)
  {

   OnStart (new string[]{ "Richard" });
   while (true) {

   }
  }

Answer (score 4):

A lot of answers here suggest having a 'parent app' that does it, but you end up with the same problem with the parent app - it's turtles all the way down.

In many unix type systems (especially historically), The init process is the first process that executes, and will execute (and restart automatically) processes as defined in /etc/inittab.

So instead of writing your own watchdog or process to auto-restart - you can use this one that does the job for you automatically, and since it's the init process, if it dies, the system has a lot more to worry about than your service.

@doron suggests another good approach, if your service should spawn a new process for every incoming connection, and only does work when it has an incoming connection.

Finally, these days the init process (and /etc/inittab) has been replaced on Ubuntu type systems with upstart - http://upstart.ubuntu.com/ - a more flexible system for the same thing.

Comment: I assume you downvoted my answer and posted your own one. In short: it's not turtles all the way down. The parent app is very small and because of that, totally reliable, so it won't crash. There's no need for a control app for the parent app. Also, a lot of things can go wrong, crashing is just one of them, but your solution can only handle the crashing. Eg: what if you want to check whether a server is still handling requests or freezed?

Comment: While I agree the watchdog approach is not that hard (a shell script can do the same job), I am strongly opinionated that writing your own is a very poor choice against using the system's init or service process management system.

Comment: If there are requirements for additional checks, then I am of the opinion that the process started by the system init/service management system can do those, and either monitor a second service process initiated by the same system, or one that it forks.

Comment: Finally, I accept that there are bound to be situations where using the init/service system for watchdog activities is not the best solution (or even an option), and for those situations your comments and Burgos' comments are entirely valid and helpful. I'll remove my downvotes if I can as they're incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a control app which starts and restarts it if necessary.
- Do this in your app - fork a child, run the program there, catch stop/crash and fork new child if necessary. Some working code can be found here: [monitoring the main app in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514703/monitoring-the-main-app-in-c) .

Comment: Do you know of any open source examples that achieve this? I'm honestly not even sure where to start on how to create this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126401/designing-a-monitor-process-for-monitoring-and-restarting-processes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514703/monitoring-the-main-app-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at using the [Inet Daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd). The inet daemon start a new process every time a new request comes in. So if there is a crash in your server, it just gets restarted when the next request comes in.

Comment: this assumes that the requests can be handled independently, and there is no shared state. It will also create a new process for each each request.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to write a parent app which auto-restarts a child process, on *NIX, is just using a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true;
do
    run_my_program;
done
```

You can optionally have this redirect output, run itself in the background, etc.
This doesn't address *starting* the process in the first place, but it's less work (for exactly the same result) as writing a parent process in C++.